# What's the difference between the API of Redis and StrictRedis?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I'm working on a project with redis.py, I works when I connect the app to a Redis client, but failed with StrictRedis.

So, I wanna know the difference between the two, but searched with no satisfied answer.

My project is here: https://github.com/kxxoling/librorum Sorry for the Chinese annotation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [redis-py README](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#api-reference):

> The official Redis command documentation does a great job of explaining each command in detail. redis-py exposes two client classes that implement these commands.
>   The StrictRedis class attempts to adhere to the official command syntax.

StrictRedis also has **no** backward compatibility:

> In addition to the changes above, the Redis class, a subclass of StrictRedis, overrides several other commands to provide backwards compatibility with older versions of redis-py:
>
> - `LREM`: Order of `num` and `value` arguments reversed such that 'num'
>     can provide a default value of zero.
> - `ZADD`: Redis specifies the
>     `score` argument before `value`. These were swapped accidentally when
>     being implemented and not discovered until after people were already
>     using it. The Redis class expects `*args` in the form of: `name1`,
>     `score1`, `name2`, `score2`, ...
> - `SETEX`: Order of `time` and
>     `value` arguments reversed.

So you should stick to `Redis` class if you have used `redis-py` for a long time - it has some commands' argument's order changed to seem more Pythonic (or even by accident).

Here in the source code ([client.py:class Redis](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/client.py#L1957)) you can see what have been changed.

Comment: That means they're almost no connections? Redis is for older redis, and StrictRedis is for the new one(from which version)?

Comment: @kxxoling they're pretty much the same, there are just minor differences. I'm not sure from which version the backwards compatibility was removed, but both the documentation and the source code has it covered. I updated my answer.

Comment: Redis is a subclass of StrictRedis, so the difference is the wrapped methods it supplies. In my case, I misused zadd, the arguments was turned upside down. What a stupid I am!

Answer (score 1):

I have found an older project also using `StrictRedis` and was wondering as well, looking into the answer by @Igor Hatarist it is no longer that way.

What I found: **Today it is implemented differently**. Actually if installing the current version (`v4.5.x` - March 2023) of redis-py then `StrictRedis` and `Redis` are actually the same: https://github.com/redis/redis-py/blob/318b114f4da9846a2a7c150e1fb702e9bebd9fdf/redis/client.py#L1289

This shows that it is not even longer implemented as class, nowadays it is just a constant (probably for backwards compatibility).

So it is no longer an override. Redis is currently a subclass of `AbstractRedis`: https://github.com/redis/redis-py/blob/318b114f4da9846a2a7c150e1fb702e9bebd9fdf/redis/client.py#L845

So it **does not matter** whether you use `StrictRedis` or `Redis` with `v4.5.x`